# How can I keep vertical headers in my table when I export to PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

When I export my datatable to PDF i lose the verticle headers. they no onlonger show vertically. and when I make the headers images instead of text, the header image doesn't show at all in the PDF export. anyone know why?.

here is my css for vertical text:

```
.verticaltext
{

writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
font-size:100%;
font-weight:500;
height:80px;
padding: 2px;
overflow: hidden;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
text-align:left;
line-height:130%;


}
```

Comment: What PDF export using what library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a css help. the below code return below css3 ver

```
<style>  
  h1 {  
    width: 50px;  
    font-size: 50px;  
    word-wrap: break-word;  
    letter-spacing: 20px; /* Set large letter-spacing as precaution */  
  }  
</style>
 <h1> ANAND </h1>
```

I hopes its helps to you...